pg_upgrade failing with "No such file or directory"
I was going to update my postgresql from 10 to 12, using homebrew.
What I did:
brew uninstall postgresql@10
brew install postgresql@12
I got the server running after this with brew services (but stopped it before trying pg_upgrade).
Then comes the problem. I got a db in the directory /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@10/ that I wanted to move to the new postgresql directory /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@12/.
So I used the command:
pg_upgrade -b /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@10 -B /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@12 -d /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@10 -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@12
which resulted in failure with the explanation:
check for "/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@10/postgres" failed: No such file or directory Failure, exiting
There is no folder named "postgres" in that directory but I don't believe it should be reading the documentation, and looking at others' example of how pg_upgrade is used, like this gist for example.
There DO EXIST a directory on the path to a bunch of files and folders which seem to be the same as in the documentation link above.
I have scoured the web for someone having the same problem without any luck. Do someone know what this issue might be, or can help me troubleshoot it further?
Thanks

This might be a stupid comment, but assuming the actual file name is "postgres", is there a filetype at the end (postgres.db or something) you're missing?

I dont think so. The documentation link doesn't have anything called "postgres" in the file layout, so I don't think it is supposed to be there.

For the -b and -B options you have to supply the directories that contain the postgres executable. Those are probably /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@10/bin and /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@12/bin.
Upgrading to v12 is a highly questionable idea, since that version will go out of support in 2024. Upgrade to the latest major release.

I located the postgres executable for v12 in the dir /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/bin . But there is no corresponding postgresql@10 folder in the /opt/homebrew/opt/ dir. I guess it was removed when I uninstalled. I cant reinstall it now because homebrew says v10 "is not supported upstream".
I thought it'd be possible to uninstall v10 and still migrate the data to a new version. About your note of using v12: a program that uses postgresql on my machine relies on that specific version maximum.

You cannot upgrade, or indeed start, the database without having v10 installed. No way. If necessary, build from source. If you have a program that doesn't support anything more recent than v12: get rid of that program as soon as you can.

:D Ok thank you @Laurenz Albe. The program is kind of unique in what it does so I'll have to stick with it. I managed to install v10 again with homebrew and now pointed pg_upgrade to the right place. Unfortunately v10 cant seem to start a up a server. It couldn't before I installed v12 either, which was part of the reason I installed it in the first place. As you can probably tell I'm a newbie on db infrastructure stuff.

If the data are valuable, perhaps you should hire an expert rather than fiddling around with the system and risk losing the data.

No its personal data that would be really nice to keep but I give up now anyways. Thanks for your help!
